# QCP accesing Quote Line -> Product Name

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm wondering how to find out if Product with Name for example 'Test' exist in our quote lines? :)

I'm trying function forEach on quoteLines but I don't what to do later.
Do anyone actually has some good resources to learn QCP? The documentation is not really big

Comment: When and where do you want to know that? That's a job for price rules. Price rules allows you to check complex stuff like your requirement and execute an action if the product name is found.

Comment: QCP - Quote Calculator Plugin
I'm using JavaScript plugin and it's for training purpose

Comment: Price rules are exactly what you need: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_price_rules_intro.htm&type=0
You can choose to execute the action before, during or after the calculation on the quote calculator.

Comment: You should probably add further details to your question and add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`(quoteLines != null) {
        quoteLines.forEach(function (line) {
                let productName = line.record["SBQQ__ProductName__c"];
                if(productName == 'test'){
                    console.log('I have test!');
                } 
            });
    }`